# Absolute rotation rates

Tags: ios, devicemotion, cmattitude

On iOS with `CMDeviceMotion`, I can get the device `CMAttitude` and its `CMRotationRate`. The rotation rates are in the local device coordinate system (x,y,z).

For a given `CMAttitude`, how can I determine the **absolute** rotation rates, i.e., the rates of rotation of the device in the world coordinate system (X,Y,Z) defined by the initial `CMAttitudeReferenceFrame`?

For example: say I initialise `CMMotionManager` with the `xMagneticNorthZVertical` reference frame. How can I calculate the rotation rates around the X-axis (world magnetic North) and the Z-axis (world vertical)?

Comment: Do you have a quaternion for the attitude? Do you know the convention of this quaternion?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the CMRotationRate by the CMAttitude quaternion.
This rotate the device frame to the world frame.